# Vercel Deployment of Next.js project is failing with Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, solana

When I try to build my updated version of my Next.js project I get a build error with the following error log even though when I run `npm run dev` and open the project on the local port everything is working fine.

Any thoughts?

[Here is error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A3QY.png)

Comment: Hey @daviewave, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add relevant code that could affect this issue

Comment: @daviewave are the nodejs versions on both machines the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should be able to reproduce the issue if you run the production build locally with `next build && next start`. To solve it try transpiling `@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui` with [`next-transpile-modules`](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules).

Answer (score 0):

Check your call stack in your Vercel error log. It's pointing at `@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui`:

```
export * from `./useWalletModal`
```